# Connecting to Openfire using XMPP in iPhone

Tags: iphone, xmpp, openfire, xmppframework

I was trying to implement a chat application using `Jabber`. I am using `XMPPFramework` 3.2.X. I have installed `Openfire` in my `MAC system.` I managed to connect to Openfire using `localhost`(eg.`user@localost`). localhost is my system name. But I am not able to connect to any of the IP addresses in the network. What could be the issue? How do I connect to Openfire by passing the IP address of the system that runs Openfire?

Thanks in advance

Comment: its very unlikely that your hostname is localhost.   Also this appears to be a networking question which is off topic @ stackoverflow

Comment: Server>Server Information>Server name is 'localhost'

Comment: this is not a networking issue i think because i can connect to my openfire server from Xabber(an android app in Google Play). I can connect to Openfire servers running on other systems either

Comment: The hostname 'localhost' is a default name for your local machine. It will not work from other machines.  You can use the ip or better yet the proper hostname as recognized on the network.

Comment: In my Openfire I changed the server name to the machine name on the network. A strange thing happened, it connected to another system(via the IP) once, but next time onwards this wouldn't happen. Has anyone faced this issue by any chance?